# How to return a huge generated ZIP file in Django?

Tags: python, django, zip

I would like to return a really big generated ZIP file in Django. The ZIP would include from 1000 to 5000 PDF files.

These PDF files are stored on Amazon S3.

I am using Heroku, and it has a 30 second timeout. So I can't get all the files and send a response in time.

What I tried is generating the ZIP file, in the backend, where I don't have this timeout limit. But Heroku has a 1GB Memory limit. So i can't do that either.

This is the code I used to perform this task:

```
from zipfile import ZipFile

def make_incoming_zip_file():
    zip_obj = ZipFileIncomingInvoices.objects.get(zip_file="")
    invoices = get_invoices(year, quarter)

    with ZipFile("invoices.zip", "w") as zf:
        for idx, invoice in enumerate(invoices):
            file_path = "work_folder/incoming_invoice.pdf"

            with open(file_path , "wb") as f:
                f.write(invoice.invoice_file.read())
            zf.write(filename=file_path , arcname=f"{idx+1} {invoice}.pdf")

    zip_obj.zip_file = File(open("invoices.zip", "rb"))
    zip_obj.save()
```

What would be the best way to achieve this task?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you use S3 and Django and Heroku, then indeed downloading large files is not possible AFAIK due to this 30 seconds timeout on Heroku. So you have three choices.

**The first one** is to use directly boto3 API to generate a url that will allow for a public file download. The method is [`generate_presigned_url`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.generate_presigned_url)

```
s3 = boto3.client('s3')

# Generate the URL to get 'mykey' from 'bucket-name'
url = s3.generate_presigned_url(
    ClientMethod='get_object',
    Params={
        'Bucket': 'mybucket',
        'Key': 'mykey'
    },
    expires=86400
)
```

Explained in [`boto3`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/s3-presigned-urls.html) docs.

**The second one** is to do the same thing but use `boto3` through `django-storages`. It adds a nice abstraction layer but is another layer to learn and configure but I'd be surprised if you haven't used it already  if you use Django and S3.

Example

```
d = Document.objects.last()
d.upload.storage.bucket.meta.client.generate_presigned_url('get_object', Params={'Bucket': 'mybucket', 'Key': 'mykey'})
```

For both solutions you can generate temporary tokens which will expire those urls in some milliseconds.

**The third solution** is to run Redis on Heroku and create a celery task that would be responsbile for

- downloading files from s3
- zipping them
- saving them in memory/into s3
- mailing user with relevant url that will allow him to download zipped package.

That way you probably won't run into the timeout issue, but memory might be a problem depending on your dynos, files and traffic.
But it potentially increases your costs, architecture and it might not always solve your issues depending on conditions mentioned above.

Comment: Thanks, 
But i would like to use Django to filter the invoices I want, and from that queryset, generate the ZIP file.

Comment: That's also doable but you mentioned you're running into timeout/memory problems with your dynos so if you want to download those files, generate a zip and return url while storing all of this in a memory, then you will probably kill your dyno.

Comment: Yes exactly, that's my issue :(

Comment: It is an old thread, but anyway. We use the following flow: we have a celery task which upload pdfs, create a zip and save it in s3 for 24 hours. The link to the zip we sent by email to user. Not super useful, although. And for now I m think on using web sockets to notify user and provide a link on web page after celery task finishes.

Comment: Yes our solution was to use Celery in the end. Send the task to celery, and inform the user in the frontend about it.

Comment: How did you solve the memory issue? I have a very similar issue but with images. Same workflow, celery, channels and email url. S3 storage. Works perfect until around 750mb. Anything over gets a Memory error. Any pointers in the right direction?